# Clamav: "WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net"

Tags: security, antivirus

When I enter the command:

```
  tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

It returns:

```
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:46 2016 -> WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net (IP: )
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:46 2016 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> ClamAV update process started at Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> WARNING: Local version: 0.99 Recommended version: 0.99.2
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22200, sigs: 603798, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
  Sat Sep 10 15:34:51 2016 -> --------------------------------------
```

When I do these commands:

```
   sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
   sudo freshclam -v
   sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
```

... there is no problem:

```
  tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> --------------------------------------
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> freshclam daemon 0.99 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: i386, CPU: i686)
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> ClamAV update process started at Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> WARNING: Local version: 0.99 Recommended version: 0.99.2
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22200, sigs: 603798, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
  Sat Sep 10 15:45:41 2016 -> --------------------------------------
```

But when I restart, the problem is back.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what problem? It looks normal to me (I know it's confusing but that's the kid of output it always produces)

Comment: @Abigael. If you have an answer, please post it as such. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. But merely editing it to say "resolved", without saying *how* it was resolved, is not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, everything is normal. There's no problem

Because now ClamAV has got a daemon. The daemon does the updates. So if we want to do updates manually, we need to stop the daemon first.

```
 $ tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
 Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
 Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
 Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> Reading CVD header (main.cvd): Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> WARNING: Can't get information about db.local.clamav.net:   Temporary failure in name resolution
 Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net (IP: )
 Thu Nov 10 19:55:59 2016 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22511, sigs: 853831, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> --------------------------------------

 $ sudo service clamav-freshclam stop
 $ sudo freshclam
 ClamAV update process started at Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016
 main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60,  builder: amishhammer)
 daily.cld is up to date (version: 22511, sigs: 853831, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)

 $ tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22511, sigs: 853831, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 Thu Nov 10 19:56:04 2016 -> --------------------------------------
 Thu Nov 10 20:18:57 2016 -> Update process terminated
 Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016 -> --------------------------------------
 Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016
 Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
 Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22511, sigs: 853831, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
 Thu Nov 10 20:20:26 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 283, sigs: 53, f-level: 63, builder: neo)

 $ sudo service clamav-freshclam start
```

Comment: I actually have a function for this `update_clam () 
{ 
    sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop;
    sudo freshclam -v;
    sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
}
`